# What is the good practice to capture instantaneous model status in django?

Tags: python, django, database

I have a robot model, like:

```
class Robot(models.Model):      
    version = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    can_version = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    power_status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=POWER_STATUS)
    working_status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=WORKING_STATUS)
```

I want to save the current state(all fields) of a robot into database when an error occurs, because I need these information to analyse the cause of error, and querying these information is a frequent operation.

[Model audit](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-audit/) is not what I want, for I need not to save the whole change history, but only the instantaneous state when error happens. I don't want to create a new model which duplicate all Robot fields and used to save Robot state either.

Comment: how about a logger, e.g. [sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry)

Comment: @ Hedde van der Heide Because I often need to query these information, so efficiency matters.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like status should be a seperate model/class with an FK to the robot, that way your robot has a "list" of all of its previous status' and you just need to query the latest.

```
class ModelStatus(models.Model):
    robot = models.ForeignKey(Robot)
    power_status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=POWER_STATUS)
    working_status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=WORKING_STATUS)
```

You may want to add someway to order them other than the id but thats a decision I can't really help you with.

If you don't want the whole list then you can just have two `OneToOneFields` on your `Robot`

```
current_status = models.OneToOneField(ModelStatus, null=True)
previous_status = models.OneToOneField(ModelStatus, null=True)
```

Comment: That's a choice, but actually I have lots of models, and I don't like to create ModelStatus for each model. In addition, ModelStatus must change  either whenever its reference table changes.

Comment: @lengxuehx - You could possibly use database model inheritance, (common fields then extended with custom). As for the changing, you could set a [Signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/)

Comment: That's cool, but inheritance needs a lot of work to current code(need to create many abstract model).

Comment: @lengxuehx - Thats fine, I'll leave my answer here as an option. Hope you manage to find a solution that works for you